# Select a valid choice. 41549530053 is not one of the available choices in dependent dropdown in django

Tags: django, django-forms

when i am trying use dependent drop-down i got Select a valid choice error  sometimes not all the times.The form is becoming invalid.when i print the form my selected value in the dropdown is not present in the form.

```
forms.py
@parsleyfy
class ScrubberForm(forms.Form):
    Headerchoice=[("","Select Header")]
    Templatechoice=[("","Select Template")]
    Header=forms.ChoiceField(label="Select Header",choices=Headerchoice+[ (o.iHeaderID, str(o.vcHeader)) for o in HEADERS_MASTER.objects.filter(~Q(iStatus = 2),iApprovedStatus=settings.STATUS_FLAGS['Active'])],error_messages={'required': 'Select Header' })
    Template=forms.ChoiceField(label="Select Template",choices=Templatechoice+[ ( str(o.iTemplateID), str(o.vcTemplateName)) for o in ENTITY_TEMPLATES.objects.all()],error_messages={'required': 'Select Template' })      
    file_upload=forms.FileField(label="Select File",error_messages={'required': 'Please Select a File' }) 
    def __init__(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super (ScrubberForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'}) 
            self.fields['file_upload'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'file-upload-input','onchange': "readCSV(this);","accept":".csv"})
            self.fields['Header'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'mdb-select md-form'})
            self.fields['Template'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'mdb-select md-form'})
            iEntityID=get_entity_id(request)        
            Headerchoice=[("","Select Header")]
            self.fields['Header'].choices = Headerchoice+[ (o.iHeaderID, str(o.vcHeader)) for o in HEADERS_MASTER.objects.filter(~Q(iStatus = 2),iApprovedStatus=settings.STATUS_FLAGS['Active'],iEntityID=iEntityID)]


models.py
class SCRUBBER_MASTER(models.Model):
    iScrubberID             = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    iHeaderID               = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True,default=0)
    iTemplateID             = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True,default='',max_length=30)
    vcUploadPath            = models.CharField(default='',max_length=150,blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Just a recommendation: as your choices depend on the current DB state you should set the `choices` of the field during `__init__` of the form (via `self.fields[].choices =`). Otherwise the choices are created during import of the class once when the server starts and never again. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: If you would use a ForeignKey relation from `SCRUBBER_MASTER.iHeaderID` to `HEADERS_MASTER` you could use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField - which would check for you the valid choices. You'd have to set the field's queryset in `form.__init__` very similar to what you are doing now in choices.

Comment: @Risadinha i dont have foreign key relation to my tables.the above code is not  working sometimes. But most of the times it does work.i don't understand the problem here